# Upload or Publish Multiple Artifacts to Azure DevOps Package Manager

Tags: maven, azure-devops, artifactory, package-managers, azure-artifacts

I am looking for a solution to what appears a simple problem but is proving quite difficult to crack.

I have a number of artifacts (predominantly jar files) downloaded from Artifactory and which I am looking to bulk upload to our new repository, DevOps Azure Package Manager.

I am open to any solution, ideally one that can be run from the command line or set up as an Azure DevOps (VSTS) build/release pipeline Task. The key requirement though is that it should have the capability to perform a bulk upload, not singularly. Would appreciate any positive ideas or suggestions on how to achieve this.

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. It seems like asure artifacts doesn't support "file" upload. Although, I'm able to build and push from a project

Comment: Did you find a solution or was the answer of Sylwester helpfull?
I yes, could you please add an example.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft’s Package Manager looks as norml Maven repository so You can use any method thats supports publishing artifacts to remote repository.
Here is sample with gradle https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-upload-a-list-of-jars-into-nexus-or-artifac 
Please follow standard procedure to generate credentials for Maven/Gradle to be able to publish one artifact, then adjust  sample gradle script to Your needs